# Assigning an arrays count to an int, NSNumber or NSUInteger fails

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Assigning an int, NSNumber and NSUInteger to an arrays count fails...

this is my line of code

```
 int diamondCount = [diamonds count];
```

where diamonds is an nsarray

I built the app and it threw an EXC_BAD_ACESS on that line

So i looked at the NSArray count method and found it returns an nsuinteger

So i did:

```
     NSUInteger diamondCount = [diamonds count];
```

that still threw me EXC_BAD_ACCESS so at last resort i assigned it to an nsnumber with numberWithInteger:

it stilled crashed.... any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diamonds` does not point to a real (and valid) NSArray. Check its initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *myArray;
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSValue *aValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSString *aString = @"a string";

myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aDate, aValue, aString, nil];
int i = [myArray count];
NSLog(@"%d",i);
NSInteger j = [myArray count];
NSLog(@"%d",j);
NSNumber *k = [myArray count];
NSLog(@"%d",k);
/*output
2011-11-21 17:01:48.272 test[48840:1303] 3
2011-11-21 17:01:48.272 test[48840:1303] 3
2011-11-21 17:01:48.273 test[48840:1303] 3*/
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It's an interesting exercise though, you could present it as such.